# Read the large text files into chunks line by line

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, file-io

Suppose the following lines in text file to which i have to read

```
INFO  2014-03-31 00:26:57,829 332024549ms Service1 startmethod - FillPropertyColor end
INFO  2014-03-31 00:26:57,829 332024549ms Service1 getReports_Dataset - getReports_Dataset started
INFO  2014-03-31 00:26:57,829 332024549ms Service1 cheduledGeneration - SwitchScheduledGeneration start
INFO  2014-03-31 00:26:57,829 332024549ms Service1 cheduledGeneration - SwitchScheduledGeneration limitId, subscriptionId, limitPeriod, dtNextScheduledDate,shoplimittype0, 0, , 3/31/2014 12:26:57 AM,0
```

I use the FileStream method to read the text file because the text file size having size over 1 GB. I have to read the files into chunks like initially in first run of program this would read two lines i.e. up to  "getReports_Dataset started of second line". In next run it should read from 3rd line. I did the code but unable to get desired output.Problem is that my code doesn't give the exact chunk from where i have to start read text in next run. And second problem is while reading text lines .. don't give a complete line..i.e. some part is missing in lines. Following code:

```
readPosition = getLastReadPosition();
using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fStream))
{
    rdr.BaseStream.Seek(readPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while (numCharCount > 0)
    {
        int numChars = rdr.ReadBlock(block, 0, block.Length);

        string blockString = new string(block);
        lines = blockString.Split(Convert.ToChar('\r'));
        lines[0] = fragment + lines[0];
        fragment = lines[lines.Length - 1];

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            lstTextLog.Add(line);
            if (lstTextLog.Contains(fragment))
            {
                lstTextLog.Remove(fragment);
            }
            numProcessedChar++;
        }
        numCharCount--;
    }
    SetLastPosition(numProcessedChar, logFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not use `StreamReader.ReadLine()` (note the singular, not plural)?  That reads a single line, with a line being ended by "\r", "\n", or "r\n".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to read a file line-by-line, do this:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("filename"))
{
    // process line here
}
```

If you really must read a line and save the position, you need to save the last line number read, rather than the stream position. For example:

```
int lastLineRead = getLastLineRead();
string nextLine = File.ReadLines("filename").Skip(lastLineRead).FirstOrDefault();
if (nextLine != null)
{
    lastLineRead++;
    SetLastPosition(lastLineRead, logFilePath);
}
```

The reason you can't do it by saving the base stream position is because `StreamReader` reads a large buffer full of data from the base stream, which moves the file pointer forward by the buffer size. `StreamReader` then satisfies read requests from that buffer until it has to read the next buffer full. For example, say you open a `StreamReader` and ask for a single character. Assuming that it has a buffer size of 4 kilobytes, `StreamReader` does essentially this:

```
if (buffer is empty)
{
    read buffer (4,096 bytes) from base stream
    buffer_position = 0;
}
char c = buffer[buffer_position];
buffer_position++;    // increment position for next read
return c;
```

Now, if you ask for the base stream's position, it's going to report that the position is at 4096, even though you've only read one character from the `StreamReader`.

Comment: +1. For more info check MSDN [ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Jim Mischel. I have used File.ReadLines but it causes the huge memory consumption and I/O opertation in case of more than 1 GB text file because it reads whole file at once. So i move the thought of FileStream.. what i want .. read from one by one charater upto where this get '\r' char it just give a whole line. By this way i can read the some part of file into chunks.

Comment: @Shailendra: That is not correct. File.ReadAllLines reads the entire file into memory. File.ReadLines reads line-by-line. Unless your file's lines are delimited by `\r` only, which would be unusual. For most text files, it would be either `\n` or `\r\n`.